# Display products from ShopSense API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

How do I display products from the [ShopSense API](http://shopsense.shopstyle.com/shopsense/7234015) in Rails using [shopsense-ruby](https://github.com/PopSugar/ruby-popsugar-shopping-api/)?

`JSON.parse(response)["products"]` is returning nil:

```
NoMethodError in Main#index
Showing /home/dev/demo-shopsense/app/views/shared/_shopsense.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #2):

  <div class="custom_widget">
    <% if @products.any %>
      <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <div class="product">
          <%= image_tag product['image']['url'] %>
          <p><%= product['name'] %></p>
```

`main_controller.rb`:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    client = Shopsense::API.new('partner_id' => 'uid0000-0000000-00')
    response = client.get_looks("New")

    @products = JSON.parse(response)["products"]
  end
end
```

`shared/_shopsense.html.erb`:

```
<div class="custom_widget">
  <% if @products.any? %>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <div class="product">
        <%= image_tag product['image']['url'] %>
        <p><%= product['name'] %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I've set up a simple demo app [demo-shopsense](https://github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/demo-shopsense) that should be easy to get up and running.

Comment: What does response looks like, Have you printed `JSON.parse(response)`??, look like `get_looks` is not returning `products` in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsed response of your request looks like this:

```
{"totalCount"=>"536121",
 "looks"=>
  [{"id"=>"12328367",
    "title"=>"black",
    ...
```

As you can see instead of 'products' we have 'looks'.

```
@products = JSON.parse(response)["looks"]
```

When you are working with external services, it's very important to find out the exact format of the response.

EDIT: 
I think in this case you actually need to use 'search' method on the client instead of 'get_looks', if you want to get products.

Comment: By the way man, any chance you're up for hire for a short gig?